# zigbee compatibility with 802.15.4-2006

Tags: networking, zigbee, ieee

I have a zigbee pro stack ported on 802.15.4-2003 MAC version.
Now my task is to port this zigbee pro stack on 802.15.4-2006.

I have read the differences between 802.15.4-2003 and 802.15.4-2006, i think there is no change related to MAC primitives that is exposed to next higher layer.

Also the zigbee pro stack which is to be ported only uses the MLME-SET,MLME-GET and other primitives of MAC , since this primitives did not change, can i just replace the primitive call of zigbee pro for 802.15.4-2003 with 802.15.4-2006 and will that not affect any functionality of zigbee pro stack due to differences between 802.15.4-2003 and 802.15.4-2006?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is not change between 2003 and 2006 versions about the MAC layer. 2006 version adds new features in the Physical layer.